# Unable to insert into an always encrypted table using PowerShell

Tags: sql, powershell, encryption, always-encrypted

I'm not able to insert into an always encrypted table using PowerShell, the code I'm using is:

```
$serverName = "ServerName"
$databaseName = "SecureDB"
$connStr = "Server = " + $serverName + "; Database = " + $databaseName + "; 
Integrated Security = True; Column Encryption Setting = Enabled"
$connection = New-Object 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connStr
$connection.Connect()
$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($connection)
$database = $server.Databases[$databaseName]
$query = @"
DECLARE @Param1 VARCHAR(50) = 'Param1Value'
DECLARE @Param2 VARCHAR(500) = 'Param2Value'
DECLARE @Param3 VARCHAR(50) = 'Param3Value'
DECLARE @Param4 VARCHAR(100) = 'Param4Value'

Insert into [dbo].[SecureTable]
values (@Param1,@Param2,@Param3,@Param4)
GO
"@
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ConnectionString $connStr
```

Note that only Param2 is encrypted and I'm using the same query on SSMS successfully.

Error message:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@Param2'. The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'PLAINTEXT') and the expression near line '6' expects it to be (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', 
>   encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'SecureDB') (or weaker).

Comment: I am not an SQL expert but is this something you can do? `$param2 = $plaintext | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force`

Comment: It has nothing to do with PowerShell SecureString, read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Invoke-sqlcmd doesn't support insert statement against encrypted columns as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931155/insert-data-using-powershell/43943345#43943345), the solution I found is to insert using SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method ()
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

```
$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=ServerName;Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=SecurePasswords; Column Encryption Setting=enabled;"
$sqlConn.Open()
$sqlcmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlcmd.Connection = $sqlConn
$sqlcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.SecureTable (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) VALUES (@Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @)"
$sqlcmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Param1",[Data.SQLDBType]::VarChar,50)))
$sqlcmd.Parameters["@Param1"].Value = "$Param1"
$sqlcmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Param2",[Data.SQLDBType]::VarChar,500)))
$sqlcmd.Parameters["@Param2"].Value = "$Param2"
$sqlcmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Param3",[Data.SQLDBType]::VarChar,50)))
$sqlcmd.Parameters["@Param3"].Value = "$Param3"
$sqlcmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Param4",[Data.SQLDBType]::VarChar,100)))
$sqlcmd.Parameters["@Param4"].Value = "$Param4"
$sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
$sqlConn.Close()
```