# Insert data into "Always encrypted" Azure SQL DB table using powershell

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, always-encrypted

I have a Azure SQL DB with [Always encrypted table and keys stored in Azure KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/always-encrypted-azure-key-vault-configure?tabs=azure-powershell). I wish to insert data into the "always encrypted" table using Powershell.

I understand the Invoke-sqlcmd does not support and I am using the SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method () to achieve the same

```
    $connStr = "Server={0};Database={1};User ID={2};Password={3};Column Encryption Setting=enabled;" -f $SqlDBServerInstance, $SqlConnectionInfo.DatabaseName, $SqlConnectionInfo.UserName, $SqlConnectionInfo.Password
    
    $sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConn.ConnectionString = $connStr
    $sqlConn.Open()
    $sqlcmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $sqlcmd.Connection = $sqlConn    
    $sqlcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.SecureTable (Column1) VALUES (@Param1)"
    $sqlcmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Param1", [Data.SQLDBType]::VarChar,50)))
    $sqlcmd.Parameters["@Param1"].Value = "$Param1"
    
    $sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I run this code I get below error even though I have right cryptographic access (Unwrap, Wrap, Verify, Sign) given to the service principal at key vault level in azure

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Failed to
> decrypt a column encryption key. Invalid key store provider name:
> 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. A key store provider name must denote either a
> system key  store provider or a registered custom key store provider.
> Valid system key store provider names are: 'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE',
> 'MSSQL_CNG_STORE', 'MSSQL_CSP_PROVIDER'. Valid (currently registered)
> custom key  store provider names are: . Please verify key store
> provider information in column master key definitions in the database,
> and verify all custom key store providers used in your application are
> registered  properly."

The way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483631/unable-to-insert-into-an-always-encrypted-table-using-powershell) does not work for me probably due to I am using Key Vault to store my keys.

To resolve this error, there is one step needed [from C# to use InitializeAzureKeyVaultProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/always-encrypted-azure-key-vault-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#register-the-azure-key-vault-provider) but since I am trying to achieve this from Powershell and SqlServer PS module only, is there any way I can achieve this using Powershell only? Without going the C# way explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/always-encrypted-azure-key-vault-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#register-the-azure-key-vault-provider)

Comment: You do not need to add the key in code.  You can always load the key using the Internet Options in your browser.  It is only done once.

Comment: sorry @jdweng, did not fully understand. _internet options in your browser_?

Comment: For IE : Tools : Internet Options : Content.  The keys are in the certificate.

Comment: I think jdweng's referring to the [Windows Certificate Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/always-encrypted-certificate-store-configure) article, which is sibling to your Azure Key Vault link. I believe the wizard there is creating the CMK and CEK as X509.2 certificates in your Personal Certificate store, which you can also manipulate via the Security settings in Internet Options, but is different to Azure Key Vault.

Comment: Okay, Thanks @AlwaysLearning, but we are using KeyVaults to manage the keys and not Windows Certificate Store, so I believe we need some different solution to initializeAzureKeyvault provider and insert the data in encrypted table

Comment: I've not tried it from PowerShell, sorry, but I'd imagine you're going to have to start with `Add-Type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider.dll'`, initialize the provider, and apply `$sqlConn.ColumnEncryptionSetting = [SqlConnectionColumnEncryptionSetting]::Enabled` just like the C# code does. I don't imagine there's going to be a pure PowerShell solution for this unless you crack open .NET Reflector to see what AzureKeyVaultProvider is doing behind the scenes and implement it.